# What is the order of $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(n-i)(k-i)\log(k-i)$?

Tags: asymptotics

Let $n<k$ and

$$f(n,k)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(n-i)(k-i)\log(k-i)$$

What is $O(f(n,k))$?

I cannot solve this. Can you help?

With simply inequalities, I found that $f(n,k) = O(n^2k\log(k))$.

Comment: Your upper bound is clearly correct. It's actually the correct order of magnitude as well: you can get a similar lower bound for only the terms of the sum where $i \le n/2$.

Comment: So it is actually $\Theta(n^2k\log k)$, right?

Comment: Correct - but can you see where the lower bound comes from?

Comment: No, I can't see that.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the sum,
my inclination is to
get $i$ by itself inside the $\log$
and distribute.

We must have
$i < k$.
Since we can have
$i = n-1$,
$n-1 < k$
so $n \le k$.

Let $k = n+m$
where $m \ge 0$.

$\begin{array}\\
f(n,k)
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(n-i)(k-i)\log(k-i)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(n-i)(n+m-i)\log(n+m-i)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(i)(i+m)\log(i+m)\\
&=\sum_{i=m+1}^{m+n-1}(i-m)i\log(i)\\
&=\sum_{i=m+1}^{m+n-1}i^2\log(i)-m\sum_{i=m+1}^{m+n-1}i\log(i)\\
&=S_2(m+n-1)-S_2(m)-m(S_1(m+n-1)-S_1(m))\\
&=S_2(k-1)-S_2(k-n)-(k-n)(S_1(k-1)-S_1(k-n))\\
&< S_2(k)\\
\end{array}
$

where
$S_j(n)
=\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^j\log(i)
$.

Approximating the sums by integrals
(and using Wolfy),
$S_k(n)
\approx \frac{m^{k + 1} ((k + 1) \ln(m) - 1)}{(k + 1)^2}
\approx \frac{m^{k + 1}  \ln(m)}{k + 1}
$
so
$S_1(m)
\approx \frac12 m^2\ln(m)
$
and
$S_2(m)
\approx \frac13 m^3\ln(m)
$.

Therefore
$f(n, k)
= O(k^3\ln(k))
$.

If you know more about
the values of $n$ and $k$,
you can get a more accurate estimate.